# How can I call documents.open and avoid the 'file in use' dialog?

Tags: vba, delphi, ms-word, word-automation

I am writing some very [simple code](https://github.com/tobya/DocTo) to open a word document, save it in a new format and close document.   However I run into problems if the document has been left in a locked state and get the 'File in Use' dialog.

[image: File in Use Dialog]

Now I would be delighted to pick option 1 or 3 automatically, but can't seem to find a way.  Ideally I would prevent it from showing at all via a parameter on the open method.  I'm using Delphi, but that's not really relevant.

```
    Wordapp.documents.Open(InputFile);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Calling open with ReadOnly set to true seems to fix this issue.

```
    Readonly := true;
    Wordapp.documents.Open(FName, false, Readonly);  //3rd parameter is readonly
```

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835182.aspx

Comment: Just what I was looking for thanks.  appWord.Documents.Open("c:\test\WK14.doc", False, True, , , , , , , , , False)   The false at the end stops it being visible as well if anyone wants that function.